# how to solve my problem? pls help me. i want to upgrade my laravel project 5.2 to 7. But composer return this problem

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Exceptions\Handler does not exist in G:\xampp\htdocs\shomoynews_dynamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:809
Stack trace:
#0 G:\xampp\htdocs\shomoynews_dynamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(809): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\Exceptions\\...')
#1 G:\xampp\htdocs\shomoynews_dynamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(691): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Exceptions\\...')
#2 G:\xampp\htdocs\shomoynews_dynamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(796): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\\Exceptions\\...', Array, false)
#3 G:\xampp\htdocs\shomoynews_dynamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(269): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('App\\Exceptions\\...', Array, false)
#4 G:\xampp\htdocs\shomoynews_dynamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(805): Illuminate\Con in G:\xampp\htdocs\shomoynews_dynamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 811
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Exceptions\Handler does not exist in G:\xampp\htdocs\shomoynews_dynamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:809
Stack trace:
#0 G:\xampp\htdocs\shomoynews_dynamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(809): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\Exceptions\\...')
#1 G:\xampp\htdocs\shomoynews_dynamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(691): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Exceptions\\...')
#2 G:\xampp\htdocs\shomoynews_dynamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(796): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\\Exceptions\\...', Array, false)
#3 G:\xampp\htdocs\shomoynews_dynamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(269): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('App\\Exceptions\\...', Array, false)
#4 G:\xampp\htdocs\shomoynews_dynamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(805): Illuminate\Con in G:\xampp\htdocs\shomoynews_dynamic\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 811
```

Comment: Going from 5.2 to 7 is a big leap. Much has changed. Look over the upgrade guides for each minor and major versjon in particular, between the two, and do the upgrade in increments. Also, a post with just a massive error doesn't help us much.

Comment: I would recommend upgrade each major version one by one, but start with going to the highest version of 5 before upgrading. The upgrade guide for each will be able to go over any breaking change in each major release. It's going to take a while, but it is much better than doing it all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like - for whatever reason - your Exception handler is missing. It should be in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`. If it's there, you might have an autoload issue.

If not, it looks like you unintentionally deleted it. You can find the source file (of version 7.x) here:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/7.x/app/Exceptions/Handler.php

Insert that file to your code.

Comment: Nevertheless, what the commentators say is absolutely right. Look at the Laravel upgrade guides and increase version number step by step. A lot has changed since 5.2